# Select from two tables with LEFT JOIN - return only one or null connection

Tags: t-sql, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aggregate SQL Function to grab only the first from each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773417/aggregate-sql-function-to-grab-only-the-first-from-each-group)

Hello everyone,

Suppose I have a view with the following select statement like this one:

```
select app.[applicationid], apref.personid as backupdbaid
from application.VW_APPLICATION app
left join general.applicationpersonroleref apref
    on (apref.applicationid = app.applicationid and apref.roleid = 3)
left join person.person secondary
```

Which will naturally return the applications with NULL backupdbaid when there is no backup dba in the connection table and N rows in case the application has N backup dbas.

The problem is: I need to acquire either null or *one* row of the connected DBAs. The returned row doesn't actually matter, as long as it is just one.

Which one is the best way to do it?

Thanks a lot for your help!