# Return detail data related to the corresponding MAX(datetime) value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by, max

I have the following dataset using SQL Server 2005:

```
TABLE NAME: LOG

TYPE       TIMESTAMP            USERID
Job        26/03/2013 00:24     DED
Job        21/03/2013 02:31     EGA
Sales      NULL                 NULL
Sales      NULL                 NULL
```

I would like to retrieve the columns TYPE, TIMESTAMP & USERID based on the MAX(timestamp).. i.e the result should be

```
Job        26/03/2013 00:24     DED
```

I've tried the following

```
SELECT max(timestamp), UserID
FROM log
GROUP BY UserID
```

however that returns all rows.

When I try

```
SELECT max(timestamp), max(UserID)
FROM log
GROUP BY UserID
```

that returns

```
Job        26/03/2013 00:24     EGA
```

I understand the max(userID) being returned is the max column value sorted alphabetically.

Lastly when i try

```
SELECT * 
FROM log 
WHERE timestamp = (SELECTmax(timestamp) FROM log)
```

i get no result (empty)..

If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT UPDATE:**

If its of any help- i should mention I have multiple tables and would and need to `SELECT` the `USERID` with the `MAX(timestamp)`WHERE TYPE` can equal either ('Job' or 'Sales')..

I am finding this works perfectly:

```
SELECT Type,
       MAX(CASE WHEN log.Type IN ('Job', 'Sales') THEN log.Timestamp ELSE NULL END) As Timestamp,
FROM log
```

The problem now is when i try:

```
SELECT Type,
       MAX(CASE WHEN log.Type IN ('Job', 'Sales') THEN log.Timestamp ELSE NULL END) As Timestamp,
       MAX(CASE WHEN log.Type IN ('Job', 'Sales') THEN log.UserID ELSE NULL END) As UserID,
FROM log
```

it gives me the max(userID) based on alphabetical order, not based on the max(timeframe)..

I need the MAX(timeframe) AND corresponding UserID when TYPE = JOB or SALES

**(to place at the end of a big select query with many other columns).**

---

**SAMPLE QUERY UPDATE:**

here is the query i am trying to perform.. am terribly sorry for my lack of indepth knowledge!

```
DECLARE @FROMDATE AS DATETIME, @TODATE AS DATETIME;
SET @FROMDATE = '1 Mar 2013'; SET @TODATE = '31 Mar 2013';

SELECT CASE WHEN country.country_code IN (61,64,673,60,65,679,66,62,92,84,63,91) THEN 'APAC'
            WHEN country.country_code IN (81,82,852,853,886) THEN 'EAST ASIA'
            WHEN country.country_code IN (44,353,32,45,358,33,49,30,39,352,356,47,351,34,46,31) THEN 'EUROPE'
            WHEN country.country_code IN (1,101) THEN 'USA/CANADA' ELSE 'OTHER'
       END AS REGION,

       info.Status as STATUS, info.Code as CODE,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, info.Start_Date,103) as 'START DATE', 

       log.Type AS TYPE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN log.Type IN ('Job','Sales') THEN log.Timestamp ELSE NULL END) As TIMESTAMP,   -- this works fine! :)
       MAX(CASE WHEN log.Type IN ('Job','Sales') THEN log.UserID ELSE NULL END) As USERID  --having trouble with this! :(

FROM log JOIN info ON (log.id = info.id), country

WHERE info.date BETWEEN @FROMDATE AND @TODATE
      AND info.Status NOT LIKE '%NA%'

GROUP BY country.code, info.status, info.code, info.start_date, log.type
```

i hope that helps guys and thank you again for the AMAZING support. I am guessing this is something simple but i'm missing something..

Comment: Your last query should work, did you get any error message?

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for your reply. The last query gives me no records (blank result).

Answer (score 1):

I created the following sample test table based on your question:

```
CREATE TABLE Log (TYPE VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, TIMESTAMP DATETIME NULL, USERID VARCHAR(3) NULL);

INSERT INTO Log
VALUES ('Job', '03/26/2013 00:24', 'DED'), ('Job', '03/21/2013 02:31', 'EGA'), ('Sales', NULL, NULL), ('Sales', NULL, NULL);
```

I tried your last sample query and it worked properly.  Since this query didn't work for you, I wrote the following which should also work and handles scenario that you have more than one row with the same TIMESTAMP value:

```
WITH BaseData
AS
    (SELECT *
        , ReverseOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC)
    FROM Log)
SELECT *
FROM BaseData
WHERE ReverseOrder = 1;
```

Comment: Hi there, this also worked great, loved the idea of adding an order column.

Comment: Hi there, this worked great but i am having trouble incorporating this with multiple tables. I have multiple tables joined (so have select statements beforehand), and need to SELECT the USERID with the max(timestamp) where TYPE IN ('Job', 'Sales')..

Comment: To help with above- In essence I would like to join this with my previous `SELECT` statements and additional `WHERE` clauses with JOINS from other tables.  So this column (SELECT the USERID with the max(timestamp) where TYPE IN ('Job', 'Sales')) is the last column of the query I am trying to create.. Help! (and thanks!)

Comment: If you could post your sample query, that would be helpful.  Also, your original code "SELECT * 
FROM log 
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM log)" should work.  Can you provide a create table script and an insert with sample values script that returns nothing?  It doesn't make senes.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my answer on another question to grab the first or last row in a table, based on a date column : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10111071/452792

You can try :

```
DECLARE @FROMDATE AS DATETIME, @TODATE AS DATETIME;
SET @FROMDATE = '1 Mar 2013'; SET @TODATE = '31 Mar 2013';

;WITH LOG_CTE AS 
(
  SELECT Stuff(Max(Convert(Varchar, Timestamp, 20) + IsNull(Convert(Varchar, Id), '')), 1, 19, '') As Id
       , Max(Type) As Type
       , Max(timestamp) As Timestamp
       , Stuff(Max(Convert(Varchar, Timestamp, 20) + IsNull(Convert(Varchar, UserID), '')), 1, 19, '') As UserID
    FROM log 
   GROUP BY log.Type 
  HAVING log.Type IN ('JOB','SALES')
)
SELECT CASE WHEN country.country_code IN (61,64,673,60,65,679,66,62,92,84,63,91) THEN 'APAC'
            WHEN country.country_code IN (81,82,852,853,886) THEN 'EAST ASIA'
            WHEN country.country_code IN (44,353,32,45,358,33,49,30,39,352,356,47,351,34,46,31) THEN 'EUROPE'
            WHEN c.country_code IN (1,101) THEN 'USA/CANADA' ELSE 'OTHER'
       END AS REGION,

       info.Status as STATUS, info.Code as CODE,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, info.Start_Date,103) as 'START DATE', 

       log.Type AS TYPE,
       log.Timestamp,
       log.UserID

FROM LOG_CTE log JOIN info ON (log.id = info.id)

WHERE info.date BETWEEN @FROMDATE AND @TODATE
      AND info.Status NOT LIKE '%NA%'
```

Comment: Dominic, this was brilliant, very simple solution. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Dominic, is it possible to modify this to retrieve with a condition or WHERE clause? i.e i've tried to put this in my query:       `(SELECT Stuff(Max(Convert(Varchar, Timestamp, 20) + IsNull(Convert(Varchar, UserID), '')), 1, 19, '') FROM log WHERE log.Type IN ('JOB','SALES')) AS UserID`  but that gives me LOTS of duplicate records..

Comment: If what you want is to retrieve the last `USERID` for each `TYPE`, use `GROUP BY/HAVING` : `SELECT Stuff(Max(Convert(Varchar, Timestamp, 20) + IsNull(Convert(Varchar, UserID), '')), 1, 19, '') 
FROM log
group by log.type
HAVING log.Type IN ('JOB','SALES')`

Comment: I would like to retrieve the `USERID` based on the `MAX(timestamp)`, with the `TYPE` as a criteria. The `TYPE` may be either ('JOB' or 'SALES')..  so to rephrase- I only want to retrieve the `USERID` when the `MAX(timestamp)` occurs when TYPE IN ('JOB', 'SALES').. I hope that makes sense! Thank you kindly once again.

Comment: Ok then try `SELECT Stuff(Max(Convert(Varchar, Timestamp, 20) + IsNull(Convert(Varchar, Case When log.Type IN ('JOB','SALES') Then UserID Else Null End), '')), 1, 19, '') FROM log`. This will return only one row with the userid for the last timestamp. It will return a NULL value if the type is not job or sales.

Comment: Hi Dominic thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this gives NULL values in the `USERID` column result.. I have been playing with it over the past hour but to no avail..   I have updated the main thread to explain something else i've tried and what i want to acheive given your help.

Comment: I am sorry but my I can't understand what you want. I gave you an answer that returns two rows, one with JOB and the other with SALES, and I gave you an answer that returns one row, with the latest data for either JOB or SALES. Try `SELECT Max(Type), Max(Timestamp), Stuff(Max(Convert(Varchar, Timestamp, 20) + IsNull(Convert(Varchar, UserID), '')), 1, 19, '') FROM log group by log.type HAVING log.Type IN ('JOB','SALES')`. What different output would you like?

Comment: Sorry, try `SELECT Max(Type), Stuff(Max(Convert(Varchar, Timestamp, 20) + IsNull(Convert(Varchar, Timestamp), '')), 1, 19, '') , Stuff(Max(Convert(Varchar, Timestamp, 20) + IsNull(Convert(Varchar, UserID), '')), 1, 19, '') 
FROM log 
group by log.type 
HAVING log.Type IN ('JOB','SALES')`

Comment: Dominic, thank you again for your painstaking effort. On the table `log` (alone) these statements work, but I cannot get them to work in my query.?

Comment: Updated my answer for complete query.

Comment: Hi Dominic, I now receive the error    `Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
Invalid object name '#log'.`

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer, I used a temporary table to build the query locally.