# How to get first available value in a column (not MIN) using aggregate function on a NVARCHAR type column?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a temp table (#TempTable) which looks like this:

```
AID         StartTime   EndTime     StartSID EndSID     Name
```

---

```
79F05D45    2013-07-02  2013-07-03  1226349  1227338    
79F05D45    2013-07-03  2013-07-03  1227381  1227901    
79F05D45    2013-07-03  2013-07-03  1233976  1233977    John Pringle
79F05D45    2013-07-03  2013-07-03  1234386  1234452    
79F05D45    2013-07-03  2013-07-03  1235138  1235147    
79F05D45    2013-07-03  2013-07-03  1235669  1235708    Mike Gordon
79F05D45    2013-07-03  2013-07-03  1235828  1239004    Jeff Smith
```

How do I use the Aggregate function on **Name** so that when I `GROUP BY` **StartTime** and **EndTime** I get **John Pringle** in the **Name** column (I tried using `MIN(Name)` but it gives me blank value and If I use `MAX(Name)` I get **Jeff Smith** )

Basically, my requirement is to get the first available value in column **Name**

**Here is my Query:**

```
SELECT
    TT.AID,
    MIN(StartTime) as StartTime,
    MAX(EndTime) as Endtime,
    MIN(StartSSID) as StartSID,
    MAX(EndSSID) AS EndSID,
    -- I tried MIN(Name) here but I get empty cell, MAX(Name) gives wrong result. Basically I want first available value in the Name column here (which is John Pringle).
    FROM
        #TempTable TT
    GROUP BY TT.AID, StartTime, EndTime
```

**Result I get:**

```
AID         StartTime   EndTime     StartSID EndSID     Name

79F05D45    2013-07-02  2013-07-03  1226349  1227338    
79F05D45    2013-07-03  2013-07-03  1227381  1239004
```

**Result I am aiming for:**

```
AID         StartTime   EndTime     StartSID EndSID     Name

79F05D45    2013-07-02  2013-07-03  1226349  1227338        
79F05D45    2013-07-03  2013-07-03  1227381  1239004    John Pringle
```

Thanks!

Comment: I hope there are no text columns as the title indicates

Comment: I was referring to string (NVARCHAR) type column. I just used generic term "text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH a as
(
SELECT
    AID,
    StartTime,
    EndTime,
    StartSSID,
    EndSSID,
    rn = row_number() over (partition by AID,cast(starttime as date) order by case WHEN name = '' or name is null then '20990101' else starttime end, starttime)
    FROM
        #TempTable TT
)
SELECT AID, StartTime, EndTime, StartSSID, EndSSID
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: What about Group By TT.AID ?

Comment: @Learner I dont see any reason for needing that

Comment: This is just sample data. I have multiple AIDs in the data. Sorry for confusion. I need Group By solution if possible.

Comment: I looked into this approach before posting the question. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773417/aggregate-sql-function-to-grab-only-the-first-from-each-group

Comment: @Learner added AID to the partition clause. That should resolve it

Comment: Are you sure Partition By works with multiple columns? I get duplicate rows.

Comment: @Learner if you want the first name for each AID every day, then this works. If you need something else, you should explain what you need

Comment: I need exactly what you said, first name for AID. But I am getting the second one for some reason.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33666/discussion-between-t-clausen-dk-and-learner)